# Infer parent class generic type from child class constructor

Tags: typescript

Here's a piece of code representing my problem:

```js
class Parent<T = unknown> {
    constructor(private prop: T) {}

    getProp(): T {
        return this.prop;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super({
            baba: 10,
            bobo: 20
        });
    }
}

const instance = new Child();
const prop = instance.getProp();
//    |
//    '-> prop is of type `unknown`
```

I would like TypeScript to understand the type of the parent class, just with the object value, without explicitly giving it the type.

In this case, we should have `Parent<{baba: number, bobo: number}>`

Is that possible?

Comment: It is not possible; there’s a feature request at [ms/TS#36456](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36456) for it. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @jcalz, it completely addresses my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way for this to happen in TypeScript.  When you write `class Child extends Parent {⋯}`, that's equivalent to writing `class Child extends Parent<unknown> {⋯}`, because `unknown` is the [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) in the `Parent<T>` declaration.  Leaving off the `T` doesn't cause the compiler to *infer* `T`, it just falls back to the default.

In fact there is no way to ask the compiler to infer `T` there; [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference only happens when you call a generic function (or `new` a generic constructor).  No such feature exists for generic types, interfaces, or classes.  Even if such a feature did exist, it still might not automatically happen based on the call to [`super()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

There is a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#36456](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36456) asking for such functionality. If that ever gets implemented, then you'll be able to do it.  But it only has a handful of upvotes, and even if you and a whole bunch of like-minded folks go there and give it a , it's still not a guarantee that it would ever happen. For now you'll just have to work around it by manually specifying the type argument via `class Child extends Parent<{baba: number, bobo: number}> {⋯}`. Yes, it's redundant, but at least it works.